# Adjust a timestamp across weekdays

Tags: postgresql

I have a table in Postgres with weekdays and a time (hours in 24h mode). Like:

```
weekday | time
---------------
sun     | 04
wed     | 23
```

Now I need those times 5 hours earlier. How do I get to:

```
weekday | time
---------------
sat     | 23
wed     | 18
```

Comment: You should be using a _single_ timestamp column rather than separating the weekday from the hour as you are currently doing.  If you had a single column, you could just use `col - interval '5 hour'`

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen As to my understanding that only works when I have a complete timestamp with year, month, day. But I only have the day of the week.

Comment: then it is impossible to guess day saving time hour switch?..

Comment: I believe any top database person on this site would also recommend that you use a timestamp column.  If you _must_ proceed this way, then you will probably have to convert between days and hours and back again, which is a lot of (unnecessary) work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

another not less ugly way:

```
t=# with a as (
  with
    i as (select 5 h)
  , a as (
    select to_char(g, 'dy'),g delta
    from generate_series('2017.05.15','2017.05.21','1 day'::interval) g
  )
  select s145.*,delta + (time||' hours')::interval - concat(h,' hours')::interval nt
  from s145
  join i on true
  join a on a.to_char = weekday
)
select to_char(nt, 'dy'), to_char(nt,'HH24')
from a;
 to_char | to_char
---------+---------
 sat     | 23
 wed     | 18
(2 rows)
```

and for eg 2 hours:

```
t=# with a as (
  with
    i as (select 2 h)
  , a as (
    select to_char(g, 'dy'),g delta
    from generate_series('2017.05.15','2017.05.21','1 day'::interval) g
  )
  select s145.*,delta + (time||' hours')::interval - concat(h,' hours')::interval nt
  from s145
  join i on true
  join a on a.to_char = weekday
)
select to_char(nt, 'dy'), to_char(nt,'HH24')
from a;
 to_char | to_char
---------+---------
 sun     | 02
 wed     | 21
(2 rows)
```

I took `'2017.05.15'` because I know it is last monday. It will respect time switch that probably not what the op wants. of course it is easily avoidabe with set timezone to 'utc'. But I don't want to complicate already ugly code even more

Comment: That's nice work. I was thinking of converting the weekday over, but I don't use Postgres often and it would have taken me some time to figure out all the pieces. I like this answer a lot.

Comment: I think this what @Tim meant by " lot of (unnecessary) work" :)

Comment: Yea... I was trying to think of a better way to handle this. I assume this is like a weekly schedule table or something that isn't specific to any one week, but if were to built it, perhaps I would pick a "Model" week and store as timestamp so one could do proper arithmetic. At least it would save a few dozen cpu cycles per record.

Comment: ugly but spendid!

Answer (score 2):

You can use a CASE statement to get the results you desire. It just gets a little ugly, but it's not unmanageable.

```
SELECT
    CASE WHEN time - 5 < 0 THEN
        CASE 
            WHEN weekday = 'Sun' THEN 'Sat'
            WHEN weekday = 'Sat' THEN 'Fri'
            WHEN weekday = 'Fri' THEN 'Thu'
            WHEN weekday = 'Thu' THEN 'Wed'
            WHEN weekday = 'Wed' THEN 'Tue'
            WHEN weekday = 'Tue' THEN 'Mon'
            WHEN weekday = 'Mon' THEN 'Sun' 
            END
        ELSE weekday
        END as weekday,
    CASE WHEN time - 5 < 0 THEN 24 - (time-5) ELSE time-5 END as time
FROM yourtable;
```

You could use a CTE so that you only have to monkey with changing that "5" in one spot too. Also adding the ability to put a positive or negative number and handle rolling forward a day:

```
WITH timeshift AS
(
    SELECT -5 as hours
)
SELECT
    CASE 
        WHEN time + timeshift.hours < 0 THEN
            CASE 
                WHEN weekday = 'Sun' THEN 'Sat'
                WHEN weekday = 'Sat' THEN 'Fri'
                WHEN weekday = 'Fri' THEN 'Thu'
                WHEN weekday = 'Thu' THEN 'Wed'
                WHEN weekday = 'Wed' THEN 'Tue'
                WHEN weekday = 'Tue' THEN 'Mon'
                WHEN weekday = 'Mon' THEN 'Sun' 
                END
        WHEN time + timeshift.hours >= 24 THEN
            CASE 
                WHEN weekday = 'Sat' THEN 'Sun'
                WHEN weekday = 'Sun' THEN 'Mon'
                WHEN weekday = 'Mon' THEN 'Tue'
                WHEN weekday = 'Tue' THEN 'Wed'
                WHEN weekday = 'Wed' THEN 'Thu'
                WHEN weekday = 'Thu' THEN 'Fri'
                WHEN weekday = 'Fri' THEN 'Sat'
                END
        ELSE weekday
        END as weekday,
    CASE 
        WHEN time + timeshift.hours < 0 THEN 24 - (time + timeshift.hours) 
        WHEN time + timeshift.hours >= 24 THEN (time + timeshift.hours) - 24
        ELSE time + timeshift.hours 
        END as time
FROM yourtable, timeshift
```